# lxml: при удалении html-тега удаляется и текст после него

Tags: python, lxml

Имеется HTML (`game_descriptions`):

```
<h2>Об этой игре</h2>
Игроки избивают, пистолет и побеждают в этом последнем стоящем 
PvP-шутере, установленном в пост-апокалиптической пустоши. Ваш 
автомобиль - ваш жизненный путь, ваше самое большое оружие, самая 
сильная броня и ваш лучший шанс опередить смертельный посягающий шторм!
<h2 class="bb_tag">ПОСЛЕДНИЙ ОДИН ПОСТОЯННЫЙ</h2><br>Звук
 вашего сердца колотится, заглушается только ревом двигателя. Вы заняли 
свое место в кругу смерти в центре апокалиптической пустоши. Вы ждете, 
когда только ваша ржавая металлическая поездка, чтобы защитить себя. Там
 лежит оружие, снаряжение и топливо, которые вам нужно, чтобы заработать
 пропитанную кровью победу...
```

Необходимо удалить первый `h2`.

Код:

```
h2 = game_descriptions.cssselect('h2')[0]
game_descriptions.remove(h2)
```

Но вместе с `h2` удаляется и этот текст, который идет после него:

```
Игроки избивают, пистолет и побеждают в этом последнем стоящем 
PvP-шутере, установленном в пост-апокалиптической пустоши. Ваш 
автомобиль - ваш жизненный путь, ваше самое большое оружие, самая 
сильная броня и ваш лучший шанс опередить смертельный посягающий шторм!
```

Я что-то не понял, ведь `h2` закрылся, по сути текст относится к родительскому элементу. Но он тоже удаляется.

Comment: Не проще просто удалить `"<h2>Об этой игре</h2>"`? `html_text = html_text.replace('<h2>Об этой игре</h2>', '')`

Comment: Интересно, что если вывести `h2_game_descriptions`, то там и будет текст после `</h2>`. Но если добавить `<br>` после `</h2>`, то будет ожидамый результат

Comment: @gil9red к первому сообщению: games_descriptions = game_descriptions.replace('<h2>Об этой игре</h2>', '')
TypeError: Argument 'old_element' has incorrect type (expected lxml.etree._Element, got str)

Comment: Забыл уточнить: необходимо сохранить все html-теги

Comment: К 2 сообщению в том то и суть. В Firefox посмотрел, там нет br, сохранил страницу на комп, и открыл в редакторе, но его там тоже нет, хотя смотря оформлению текста там он как будто есть. Можете сами посмотреть: https://store.steampowered.com/app/751240/Fractured_Lands/

Comment: А `old_element` откуда взялось?? и как оно связанно с `"<h2>Об этой игре</h2>"`? Удалите из строки html если это не нужно :) Не, у меня на работе корпоративная прокси не пустит, дома поздно вечером буду :)

Comment: old_element это в ошибке сказано, и скорее всего пишет что старый элемент (h2, который мы заменяем) не корректного типа.

Comment: Это же не строка, а дерево элементов

Comment: А вы из строки удалите

Comment: Из строки удалилось, только пустое место осталось, но я его удалил с помощью strip()

Comment: Как тогда страницу в виде строки представлять? Я строил дерево так:
def get_html(request):
    return lxml.html.fromstring(request.text)

Comment: Удаляйте ту строку с тегом из `request.text`

Comment: Не совсем понял вас

Comment: Давайте тогда по шагам: 1. `html_text = request.text` 2. `html_text = html_text.replace('<h2>Об этой игре</h2>', '')` 3. `... return lxml.html.fromstring(html_text)`

Comment: Хорошо, работает. Но появилась проблема. До этого с помощью строчки game_descriptions = ''.join(to_string(child) for child in game_descriptions.iterchildren()) я избавлялся от родительского контейнера и сохранял весь html код. Теперь она не работает: TypeError: Type 'str' cannot be serialized.

Comment: Добавил код to_string()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что lxml, в отличие от браузеров с их Text Node, не заводит отдельных элементов для простых кусков текста — они прикрепляются к ближайшему предыдущему элементу:

```
>>> import lxml.html

>>> node = lxml.html.fragments_fromstring('<div><h2>Заголовок</h2>Текст1<br/>Текст2</div>')[0]
>>> node
<Element div at 0x7f8d41070a98>
>>> h2 = node.find('h2')

# Текст внутри h2
>>> h2.text
'Заголовок'

# Текст *СПРАВА* от h2
>>> h2.tail
'Текст1'

# tostring для h2 выдаёт странное
>>> lxml.html.tostring(h2, encoding='unicode')
'<h2>Заголовок</h2>Текст1'

# Вместе с удалением h2 удаляется и текст справа
>>> node.remove(h2)
>>> lxml.html.tostring(node, encoding='unicode')
'<div><br>Текст2</div>'

# То же самое и с br
>>> node.remove(node.find('br'))
>>> lxml.html.tostring(node, encoding='unicode')
'<div></div>'
```

Чтобы обойти эту проблему, придётся покостылять — запихнуть текст в tail предыдущего элемента или, если предыдущего элемента нет (как в вашем случае), в текст родительского:

```
def remove_keeping_tail(e):
    parent = e.getparent()
    prev = e.getprevious()
    if prev:
        # Если есть предыдущий элемент, то цепляем текст ему в хвост
        # (Я дописываю «or ''», потому что tail может быть None)
        prev.tail = (prev.tail or '') + (e.tail or '')
    else:
        # Если нету, то цепляем текст родителю
        parent.text = (parent.text or '') + (e.tail or '')
    # После спасения текста удаление абсолютно безопасно
    parent.remove(e)
```

---

```
>>> node = lxml.html.fragments_fromstring('<div><h2>Заголовок</h2>Текст1<br/>Текст2</div>')[0]
>>> node.text
None

>>> remove_keeping_tail(node.find('h2'))
>>> lxml.html.tostring(node, encoding='unicode')
'<div>Текст1<br>Текст2</div>'

>>> remove_keeping_tail(node.find('br'))
>>> lxml.html.tostring(node, encoding='unicode')
'<div>Текст1Текст2</div>'

>>> node.text
'Текст1Текст2'
```

Comment: Кстати, [в английском SO есть вариант функции с проверками на None](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44141404/5418360). Чья функция лучше, не знаю (но моя короче :)

Comment: как можно получить весь текст, с html - атрибутами, но без блока родителя?

Comment: До этого делал ''.join(to_string(child) for child in game_descriptions.iterchildren()), где def to_string(node):
    return lxml.html.tostring(node, encoding='unicode'). Но сейчас в ваших случаях данный способ не работает

Comment: @danilshik если я правильно понял, слева к вашему варианту просто приплюсуйте `game_descriptions.text` (не забудьте проверку на None)

Comment: Добавил код. Текущий вариант ответа при удалении h2. Необходимо удалить родительский блок <div id="game_area_description" class="game_area_description"></div>. Необходимо именно сохранить все html-теги внутри блока, если бы мне нужен только текст я бы воспользовался .text

Comment: @danilshik получение html-кода внутри элемента — это уже совсем другой вопрос, никак не относящийся к проблеме удаления элементов

Comment: Хорошо, добавлю новый вопрос

Comment: @danilshik https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/862558

Comment: @danilshik если вам это всё помогло, отметьте ответ галочкой?

Comment: Решил вообще не парсить

Comment: @danilshik зря.

Comment: Просто я этот текст хотел в мобильном приложении использовать, думаю там будет проблема с отображением