# Аналог innerHTML для lxml

Tags: html, python, lxml

Как получить всё содержимое внутри HTML-тега в lxml, но без самого тега?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123351/equivalent-to-innerhtml-when-using-lxml-html-to-parse-html

Comment: (правда, в английском SO почему-то все ответы неполные)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Встроенного метода вроде бы нет, но нетрудно написать свой.

Проблема в том, что простой текст в lxml не является самостоятельным элементом (в отличие от Text Node в браузерах), поэтому нужно не забыть добавить `text` в начале.

```
from html import escape  # Доступно с Python 3.2
import lxml.html

def inner_html(elem):
    # Текст в самом начале внутри тега
    # (не забываем про экранирование!)
    result = [escape(elem.text or '')]

    # Все элементы-потомки
    for child in elem.iterchildren():
        result.append(lxml.html.tostring(child, encoding='unicode'))
    # Текст в конце тега принадлежит последнему элементу-потомку (tail)
    # и добавится автоматически

    # Собираем результат в одну строку
    return ''.join(result)
```

---

```
# В примере подставим &lt;br&gt; чтобы проверить экранирование
>>> node = lxml.html.fragment_fromstring(
    '<div>Тек&lt;br&gt;ст1<h2>Тек&lt;br&gt;ст2</h2>Текст3<br/>Текст4</div>'
)

>>> lxml.html.tostring(node, encoding='unicode')
'<div>Тек&lt;br&gt;ст1<h2>Тек&lt;br&gt;ст2</h2>Текст3<br>Текст4</div>'

>>> inner_html(node)
'Тек&lt;br&gt;ст1<h2>Тек&lt;br&gt;ст2</h2>Текст3<br>Текст4'
```

Comment: `fragments_fromstring(...)[0]` -> `fragment_fromstring(...)`?

Comment: @gil9red а, и правда)